# optimize parallelisation in SLURM cluster: the case of genome alignemnt

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm, genome

I would like to understand what is the best way of using bwa in parallel in a SLURM cluster. Obviously, this will depend on the computational limits that I have as user.

bwa software has an argument "-t" specifying the number of threads. Let's imagine that I use `bwa mem -t 3 ref.fa sampleA.fq.gz`, this will mean that bwa split the job on three tasks/threads. In other words, it will align three reads at a time in parallel (I guess).

Now, if I want to run this command on several samples and in a SLURM cluster, Shall I specify the number of tasks as for bwa mem, and specify the number of CPUs per task(for instance 2)? Which would be:

```
sbatch -c 2 -n 3 bwa.sh
```

where bwa.sh containes:

```
cat data.info | while read indv; do
bwa mem -t 3 ref.fa sample${indv}.fq.gz
done
```

Do you have any suggestion? Or can you improve/correct my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

With `-c 2` you are asking to have 2 CPUs per task.

With `-n 3` you are asking to have 3 tasks.

That configuration prepares a set of resources that comprises 6 CPUs in up to 3 different nodes. But your script only used 3 CPUs (`-t 3`), so you are wasting resources and probably using resources that does not belong to you (because the task will use 3 CPUs and you only asked for 2 CPUs per task).

For that specific script, `-c 3` is the proper parameter (the other defaults to one task):

```
sbatch -c 3 bwa.sh
```